# calculate show x of x entries of x in pagination table manually

Tags: angular, pagination

Hi So I'm working with table which has pagination and I need to show 1-5 of 10 entries dynamically ,how do I calculate that manually i just need the logic on how to do that so that I can understand and implement it, I'm a newbie to angular any guidance will be much helpful

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hi @Brandon thank you for the quick response as im a newbie  I'm unable to figure out the logic like how to display i had something in mind like this 'Showing' + first * currentPageRows + ' to ' + currentpageCount * currentPageRows + ' of ' + totalrows ,Does this make any sense

Comment: I've been there. On S.O., people usually want to see what you've tried and what's not working. A certain amount of effort is expected to figure out what you're trying to do before reaching out for help.

What you're looking for is some basic math. You need the total # of objects, then divide that by how many per page, taking the ceiling if there's a remainder.

Example: 11 objects / 10 per page would yield 2 pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that makes sense and sorry for not trying anything beforehand will certainly keep that in mind :)

Comment: No worries at all. Expect the avalanche of downvotes to come shortly :)